# UITableView Custom View and "Load More" in the same cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have UITableView with Custom View on it.
For the bottom of the tableview, I add a "Load More" cell there. 
After clicked, the tableview load more data successfully and the "Load More" cell still at the bottom of the tableview.
However, after I clicked the first "Load More", the second "Load More" appears, and the custom view still exist in the same cell of second "Load More". "Load More" and custom view are on the same cell. I want that cell only appear "Load More".

This problem exists for the third, fourth "Load More".
Can anyone help me?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return imageCurPos+1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([aTableView tag]==501){ 
        // Main Table
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [[cell viewWithTag:3007] removeFromSuperview];

        const NSInteger BOTTOM_LABEL_TAG = 3002;
        UIImageView *bottomLabel;
        UILabel *loadMore;


        if(indexPath.row < imageCurPos){
        if (cell == nil)
        { //All repeat things come here, if don't want to repeat here, please state outside this brucket
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

//Edited
for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }


            bottomLabel = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 30, 250, 112)] autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bottomLabel];

            bottomLabel.tag = BOTTOM_LABEL_TAG;

            cell.backgroundView =
            [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
            cell.selectedBackgroundView =
            [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];

        UIImageView *iconView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 45, 45)] autorelease];
        iconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"02_bubble.png"];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:iconView];

        bottomLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"05_bubble.png"];

        }else if(indexPath.row == imageCurPos ){ //For Load More
            if (cell == nil)
            { //All repeat things come here, if don't want to repeat here, please state outside this brucket
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }  

//Edited
for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }


                loadMore =
                [[[UILabel alloc]
                  initWithFrame:
                  CGRectMake( 0, 0, 300, 50)]
                 autorelease];

                loadMore.text = @"Load more...";
                loadMore.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

                loadMore.tag = 3007;

                loadMore.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:loadMore];            
        }
        return cell;     
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
if([tableView tag]==501){
        if([indexPath row] != imageCurPos){

        }else{ // For load more

            NSLog(@"noRow Prev: %d", imageCurPos);
            imageCurPos += interval;
            NSLog(@"noRow After: %d", imageCurPos);

            [tbl_mo_main reloadData];   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use 2 different identifiers, one for the normal cell and one for load more cell.

And one thing is that creating custom cell should be done in the block.

```
if (cell == nil)  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //  create the views in side the cell and add it
    ...
}
```

Then outside this block, update the cell. 
You can set the tag for your views in the creation of cell, and update the corresponding view by getting it with `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:tag]`

You may refer to this topic: [Reload TableViewCell's UILabels in dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358237/reload-tableviewcells-uilabels-in-dynamic-table/9358294#comment11829595_9358294)

Answer (score 0):

```
        [cell.contentView addSubview:loadMore];
```

This line adds the label to cell contentview but when the cell is reused ..that label is still present in that cell.

Add the following code after if(cell == nil) in both if and else for index path checking.

```
 for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it gave me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
I struggled on this for two days.

Comment: update your code with the changes you have done and also DO an NSLog in the start of the method to check which index path is crashing

Comment: I just added the code below under if (cell == nil), it crashes after clicked to Load More, updated in the Question

for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: i checked your code again ..remove the code i gave..apparently you are doing that in `[[cell viewWithTag:3007] removeFromSuperview];`  but you are not removing the bottom label view...so in the load more cell your bottom cell is repeated..remove that too

Comment: Thanks for your help. But after I remove [[cell viewWithTag:3007] removeFromSuperview]; the "Load More" didn't disappear at this time.